# Calling a Dim later on in the code

Tags: vb.net

I have a `Dim` that retrieves the last write time of a folder

```
Dim lastWrite As DateTime = Directory.GetLastWriteTime("F:\data")
```

Which then updates to a label

```
Label1.Text = (lastWrite)
```

This works, however I am trying to call it again later on in my code by issuing the same 2nd line, but the label does not update when I can clearly see the write time has changed in File Explorer. I need to restart my program in order for the label to be updated, does anyone know how I can recall `lastWrite`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is a little confusing but can't you just get the date directly into the label every time that you need it to be updated?

```
Label1.Text = Directory.GetLastWriteTime("F:\data")
```

Answer (score -2):

I agree with Ted's answer, but I would add that if you have Option Strict set (as you should), when you update the label1 control use:

label1.text = cDate( Directory.GetLastWriteTime("F:\data"))

This converts the result to a string.

Comment: `CDate` returns a `Date`, not a `String`. You should have `Strict` on yourself... you are relying on implecit casting.

Comment: @Codexer - Oh, the irony!

Comment: @ChrisDunaway I find it amusing as a result.